# How to pass `--` when used with pre npm scripts

Tags: bash, shell, npm, webpack, npm-scripts

How to pass others flags into npm command that has `pre` config

```
"prebuild": "npm run build:vendor",
"build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --env.production -p",
```

When I run `npm run build -- --env.produciton` the flag `--env.produciton` does not work

I want to pass into webpack command.. ending like this
 `cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --env.production -p --env.production`

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Are you trying to use the environment type (dev/prod) as a condition in your webpack config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two options to pass params, one over node `cross-env`:

```
"build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production YOUR_ENV=yourName webpack -p"
```

```
if (process.env.YOUR_ENV === 'yourName') { }
```

the other with webpack:

```
"build": "webpack --env.NODE_ENV=local --env.YOUR_ENV yourName --progress"
```

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = env => {
  // Use env.YOUR_ENV here:
  console.log('YOUR_ENV: ', env.YOUR_ENV); // 'yourName'

  return {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
  };
};
```

The param is always true if you won't set value.

https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/

```
Setting up your env variable without assignment, --env.production sets --env.production to true by default..
```